# How to profile Django on Gunicorn in production

Tags: django, profiling, gunicorn, gevent

I have a memory leak that is hard to reproduce in testing environment.
So I'd like to profile my production server for a limited time period to get an overview about which objects take up most memory.
It seems that it's not that easy to profile Gunicorn due to the usage of greenlets.

I'm running:

- Python 2.7.3
- Gunicorn 18.0
- Django 1.6

This is my Gunicorn config:

```
CONFIG = {
    'environment': {
        'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'myapp.settings',
    },
    'user': 'myapp',
    'group': 'myapp',
    'args': (
        '--bind=127.0.0.1:8088',
        '--workers=8',
        '--worker-class=socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker',
        '--timeout=300',
        '--error-logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/myapp-error.log',
        '--max-requests=100',
        '--log-level=debug',
        'myapp.wsgi:application',
    ),
}
```

Whats the best way to do memory profiling when running Django with Gunicorn?

Comment: You could try writing your own custom profiling middleware. Have a look at this: https://gun.io/blog/fast-as-fuck-django-part-1-using-a-profiler/. Although, the author there suggests it himself to not use the script the in production.

Here's a repo that claims to do some of what you want to do: https://github.com/theospears/django-speedbar

Answer (score 0):

I use the New Relic service:

http://newrelic.com/

They have free plan, with 24h data retantion.

Is very easy to setup:

http://newrelic.com/python#installation